# Media item rename doesn't publish

Tags: publishing, media-library

When we rename a media item in Content Editor, and then publish, the published item in Web DB still has the old name. I expect that the published item's name should change to the new name, so I assume this is a Sitecore bug.

This is in Sitecore XP 8.2 rev. 180406 (Update-7). It looks like similar bugs have appeared and been fixed in various versions of Sitecore, so the version is probably important.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909565/sitecore-publish-not-working-after-renaming-item appears to be the same issue, but no solution is given there.

So, does anyone know if there is a fix available and where it is?

Comment: Hope to see any answer. I have seen this issue IRL.

Comment: I have installed a fresh copy of Sitecore 8.2 Update 7.
But I am not able to reproduce this issue. I have installed this in a standalone mode. Can you share some more information on this?
However, I found an article: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/5773 which talks about the similar issue in Sitecore 8.2 Update 3 and a link to hotfix is also provided in the article.
So it seems you may have to reach out to Sitecore to get an upgraded version of the same patch that is compatible with your version.

Comment: As mentioned below in answer, confirm your version with revision. There is a bug with Sitecore 8.2 update 3.

Comment: @Gobinath: What does "confirm your version with revision" mean? I already listed our version above: Sitecore XP 8.2 rev. 180406. I already know there was a known bug in Sitecore 8.2 update 3, but I believe I've read that that bug was fixed prior to Update 7, and I think we have Update 7 (it's not easy to tell which "update number" our rev. 180406 is, because the version display in Content Editor doesn't display an update number).

Comment: @ConradAlbrecht Sitecore revision numbers and updates are directly linked, when you say rev 180406 then it should be Update-7 not other update has the similar rev numbers, but you were in doubt with the revision number in your question that's why asked you to confirm.

Comment: @Gobinath: I know revision numbers and updates are directly linked; however, it isn't obvious *which* update matches a revision number since the update number isn't published in the Sitecore UI. I wasn't "in doubt with the revision number", it's 180406. I was  (and still am, a bit, since it's not obvious) in doubt with the *update number*.

Comment: Matching the revision number with the update number is easy, just go here: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform.aspx

Comment: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/136794

Comment: @Pradeep: Thank you, but your link is a hotfix for Update 3. As I said above, I already know there's a hotfix for Update 3, but my post is about Update 7.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: Sitecore Support confirmed a bug, bug reference number #103944, and gave us a patch, which seems to fix the problem.